# PowerShell Azure Function stops while executing without error message

Tags: azure, powershell, sharepoint, azure-functions

I am using an Azure Function to create a new SharePoint site with PnP.
The Azure Function reads from a list in SharePoint that supplies all the Information needed to create a site.
This works Perfectly fine in Visual Studio Code, but not in the Azure Funktion.
The strange part is, that the after some time it just tells me the Funktion finished, eventhough some parts that syntactically cannot be skipped, got skipped.

```
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credentials $cred

    Set-PnPListItem -List list -Identity $listitem.ID -Values @{"something" = "creating..."}

    New-PnPSite -Type TeamSite -Title $listItem.Title -Alias $Listitem.Alias -Description $listItem.Description

    Set-PnPListItem -List list -Identity $listitem.ID -Values @{"something" = "The URL"
```

This part of the Code works fine in in Visual Studio, but when it's run via Azure Functions, the list-field "something" first changes to "creating…", but then the Azure Function stops:

```
[Info] Function completed (Success, Id=x, Duration=6663ms)
```

I don't really get what is Happening, and why it stops, normally i would get an error message or something.

Do you guys know whats going on?

Comment: Can you try adding  try catch in the ps script and see if you get an exception

Comment: Nope, no exception. I also wrote some Write-Outputs's in my Code, the one before the try worked, it didn't catch anything, then i got a Timeout because my function took too Long. But id actually doenst really makes sense that creating a new SharePoint site takes more than 10 minutes.

Comment: so it actually times out?

Comment: Sometimes, it makes sense when it does. But most of the time it just finishes without a timeout.

Comment: Looks like it always times out now, so the "New-PnPSite" command seems to take over 10 minutes.

Comment: If the problem is timeout, you can change the your function plan from consumption plan to app service plan. Consumption plan's maximum timeout is 10 minutes but app service plan has no limit for timeout.

Comment: i get that, but creating a new site should not take 10 minutes. Also, it looks like the sites actually got created, the Code just doesn't want to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just reinstalled all my modules to Azure Function + some new ones. After that my function worked as intended.